# Possible Z3 bug with pattens/triggers

Tags: z3

I tried running Z3 on the following smt2 file

```lisp
(set-option :print-success false)
(set-info :smt-lib-version 2.6)
(set-option :smt.AUTO_CONFIG false)
(set-option :smt.PHASE_SELECTION 0)
(set-option :smt.RESTART_STRATEGY 0)
(set-option :smt.RESTART_FACTOR 1.5)
(set-option :smt.ARITH.RANDOM_INITIAL_VALUE true)
(set-option :smt.CASE_SPLIT 3)
(set-option :smt.DELAY_UNITS true)
(set-option :NNF.SK_HACK true)
(set-option :smt.MBQI false)
(set-option :smt.QI.EAGER_THRESHOLD 100)
(set-option :smt.BV.REFLECT true)
(set-option :smt.qi.max_multi_patterns 1000)
(set-option :smt.mbqi false)
(set-option :model.compact false)
(set-option :model.v2 true)
(set-option :pp.bv_literals false)
; done setting options

(declare-sort Ref 0)
(declare-sort Field 0)
(declare-sort Mask 0)
(declare-fun select_mask (Mask Ref Field) Real)
(declare-fun zero_mask () Mask)
(declare-sort Heap 0)
(declare-fun length (Heap Ref) Int)
(declare-fun length* (Heap Ref) Int)
(declare-fun select_heap (Heap Ref Field) Ref)
(declare-fun next () Field)
(declare-fun null () Ref)
(declare-fun this () Ref)
(declare-fun mask () Mask)
(declare-fun store_mask (Mask Ref Field Real) Mask)
(assert (forall ( ( ?x0 Mask) ( ?x1 Ref) ( ?x2 Field) ( ?x3 Real)) (! (= (select_mask (store_mask ?x0 ?x1 ?x2 ?x3) ?x1 ?x2)  ?x3) :weight 0)))
(assert (forall ( ( ?x0 Mask) ( ?x1 Ref) ( ?y1 Ref) ( ?x2 Field) ( ?y2 Field) ( ?x3 Real)) (! (=> (or  (not (= ?x1 ?y1)) (not (= ?x2 ?y2))) (= (select_mask (store_mask ?x0 ?x1 ?x2 ?x3) ?y1 ?y2) (select_mask ?x0 ?y1 ?y2))) :weight 0)))
(assert (forall ((o_2 Ref) (f_4 Field) ) (! (= (select_mask zero_mask o_2 f_4) 0.0)
 :pattern ( (select_mask zero_mask o_2 f_4))
)))
(assert (forall ((heap Heap) (this Ref) ) (! (= (length heap this) (length* heap this))
 :pattern ( (length heap this))
)))
(assert (forall ((heap Heap) (this Ref) ) (! (= (length heap this) (ite (= (select_heap heap this next) null) 1 (+ 1 (length* heap (select_heap heap this next)))))
 :pattern ( (length heap this))
)))
(assert (not (= this null)))
(assert (= mask (store_mask zero_mask this next 1.0)))
(declare-fun heap () Heap)
(declare-fun valid-next () Field)
(push 1)
(set-info :boogie-vc-id test2)
(set-option :timeout 0)
(set-option :rlimit 0)
(assert
  (or (<= (select_mask mask this next) 0.0)
      (and (= (select_heap heap this next) this)
           (or (> 1.0 (select_mask zero_mask null valid-next))
               (and (<= 1.0 (select_mask zero_mask null valid-next))
                    (>= (length heap this) (length heap (select_heap heap this next))))))))
(check-sat)
(pop 1)
```

Of the Z3 versions I tried, 4.8.6 - 4.8.9 returned `unknown` but 4.8.10 - 4.9.1 returned `unsat`. The `unsat` result seems to come from triggering the `length` axioms, but it seems like if disjuncts were looked at in order, Z3 should find a partial model where `(= (select_heap heap this next) this)` and `(> 1.0 (select_mask zero_mask null valid-next))` without triggering the `length` axioms and return `unknown`. Is this a bug in Z3, or does Z3 not provide gaurentees about the order disjuncts are looked at.

I also tried removing the `push` and `pop` lines which caused all the versions of Z3 I tried to return `unsat`.

Answer (score 0):

After trimming z3 specific settings, Both CVC4 and CVC5 also return `unsat` for this query. Note that `unknown` isn't incompatible with `unsat`: It's perfectly OK for the solver to now return `unsat` for something it previously said `unknown`. (Or vice-versa.)

Given CVC4/CVC4 and z3 all agree on `unsat`, the way to debug this would be:

- See if you can get an unsat core, and if that makes sense
- Assert extra conditions that tie the model to what it should be according to your expectations. Hopefully doing that will show you why it is unsatisfiable.

If you need more help from this community, you'll have to specify exactly what model you'd consider would satisfy this formula, and debug it first to remove as much of the problem as you possibly can. Best of luck!

Comment: Hi there,

Thanks for the extra information and suggestions (I'm also involved with the original question)!

For a little more context, this query results from a verification tool which allows Z3 to instantiate quantifiers (only) via e-matching; the fact that quantifier instantiations are controlled via their triggers can be important to such tools (for predictability, performance, sometimes termination). So although it is useful to realise that this problem indeed has no first-order model, that isn't quite the end of the story, I think.

Comment: To put this another way, one could more-abstractly read this formula input as `A ^ (B V C)`  where `A` is the background axioms/facts up to the `push` command, `B` is the `(<= (select_mask mask this next) 0.0)` disjunct and `C` is the remainder of the disjunction in the last `assert`. The fact is, in a first-order logic sense, `A` has no model. However, to see this one needs to make quantifier instantiations which are guarded by patterns. These instantiations are only allowed to be made when matching ground terms arise in the context, and these are only in the *second* disjunct `C`.

Comment: So, if one modified the input to be "only" `A^B` then this formula would have no first-order model but one would still definitely expect `unknown` from the solver (given that it has only e-matching enabled). The OP also checked that this is in fact that case (and if it weren't, then the patterns would clearly not have been respected). On the other hand, for `A^C` one definitely expects `unsat` as `C` contains the terms that enable the necessary quantifier instantiation. So I'm curious as to whether/why for `A^(BVC)` one should get/expect `unsat` and not `unknown`.

Comment: By the way, getting the unsat core seems like a great suggestion to double-check that the quantifier instantiation is indeed the key to the result; the question will then definitely become whether/why that quantifier instantiation should be expected given that it is only enabled under one of the two cases (arising from `BVC`)

Comment: If I understand correctly, you're saying z3 should return `unknown` instead of `unsat`? If so, I'm not sure if relying on z3 *not* to be able to do something about quantifiers just because you turned off(?) e-matching. Z3 keeps changing underneath, and it wouldn't surprise me some new configuration might trigger it to reach the `unsat` conclusion without the e-matching path you're somehow relying on. In any case, `unsat` is always a better answer than `unknown`, so I'm not sure what you'd worry about that. (Maybe you're saying it should actually be `sat`? That'd be a bug, of course.)

Comment: Thanks! The situation is that e-matching is the *only* mechanism enabled for quantifier instantiation. In this configuration it's expected that quantifier instantiation only happens according to ground terms matching the triggers specified. This is how many program verification tools control quantifier instantiation to try to get predictable performance and results (this is still challenging to get right but it's important that extra instantiations are not made; one can think of this as a desired incompleteness for predictability reasons). I'm sure z3 should return `unknown` in some such cases

Comment: You might want to start a discussion at https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/discussions so the developers can (possibly) chime in. While I see what the upstream tools are trying to achieve, I think z3 remains (for good reasons) a moving target especially regarding how quantifiers are handled that it'd be faulty rely on specific behavior. There might be some option setting (try `z3 -pd`) that might help though.

Comment: Another idea: Turn verbose mode on (-v:10) and look at the log. I believe z3 prints a message whenever a quantifier is instantiated. Perhaps that can provide some guidance. (The log is hard to read in general, but you might be able to grep for certain keywords.)